# Rearrange Clipboard Text to Fit in Google Translation Box

Tags: text, translation, google-translate, notepad

As you may seen, when we copy text from internet or other application and paste as raw text in google translate source language box, sentences are misinterpreted by Google because of extra spaces in text.

You should remove them and reorder text to get more better translation.
I manually do this task which seems to be solvable. is there any tool or trick to fix copied text so that it placed properly in source language translation box.

Comment: I fixed it by using a tool called textfixer which is an online tool.